# ReactJS issue: () => vs function ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Was following along the ReactJS tutorial from their website.

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        <Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
        <Comment author="Jordan Walke"> This is *another* comment</Comment>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentForm">
        Comment Form
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList />
        <CommentForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById("content")
);
```

However, if I use arrow notation in the first component Comments, namely:

(*params*) => {}

instead of the normal function declaration notation, namely:

function(*params*) {}

The chrome interpreter will spit out the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Can anyone shine some light on the matter?

Comment: Arrow functions have static lexical this that can be determined by reading their declaration. In English, their this-value cannot be modified through method invocation, call, apply, or bind. Since 'this' was undefined when the function was created, it will always be undefined no matter how its called.

Comment: You can't use `this` with `=>` in the way you're assuming, `({foo: x => this}).foo(); // === window`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions will not bind `this`. So if you create your `render` function as an arrow function, the `this` will not be bound to the current component.

So, for `render` and other methods that belong to your component and need access to the component as `this`, you need to use real functions. You can use arrow functions for nested functions though (and there it makes more sense to use them).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Much apreciated.

Comment: Side note: if real functions feels heavy to write, then use ES6 classes and write React components as classes. A bit less typing involved.